# Define the meaning in Fibonacci sequence function for me a=b and b=sum , can someone please explain what they do

Tags: javascript, function, fibonacci

```
function fib (n) {
  var output = [];
    var a=0;
    var b=1;
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
      if(i===0){
        output.push(i);
      } else if(i==1){
        output.push(1);
      } else{
        var sum=a+b;
        output.push(sum);
        a=b;
        b=sum;
      }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Can you please help me define what a=b b=sum do and how it works. I really dont get it, just started learning.

Comment: These are just assignment statements, inside an else that runs in the loop when `i` is not equal to 0 or 1. The sum of a and b is stored, then a is set t b, and b is set to the sum, and the loop moves on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, both "a" and "b" are variables. They are defined outside the scope of the for loop. For this reason, their value can be mutated and persist through the life of the for loop.

ie

```
var a = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   a = a + 1;
}
console.log(a)
```

if you ran this, "a" would equal 5 at the console log.

In your example, the function gets the nth number in the Fibonacci sequence. a and b are stored values that need to carry forward in the next iteration. "a" represents the last value iterated on, while b represents the pending total.

if you passed in 6 for example:

First iteration: i is 0 so push 0.

Second iteration: i is 1 so push 1.

Third iteration: sum would be set to a (0) + b (1) so 1. a would then be set to 1 (our last known b value) and b would then be set to 1 (our new sum)

Fourth iteration: sum would be set to a (1) + b (1) so 2. a would then be set to 1 (again) and b would be set to 2.

Fifth iteration: sum would be set to a (1) + b (2) so 3. a would then be set to 2 and b would be set to 3.

Sixth iteration: sum would be set to a (2) + b (3) so 5. a would then be set to 3 and b would be set to 5.

and the for loop would end and return output, which is: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5

Those are the first 6 numbers in the Fibonacci sequence.

I hope this helps you out.